# rewrite URL and get parameter

Tags: php, url-rewriting

at the moment I have this url format:

```
www.domain.de/?paramter=value
```

with php I can access the value like this:

```
<? echo $_GET['paramter']; ?>
```

but I would like to rewrite the url to this format:

```
www.domain.de/paramter=value
```

How can I realize this with a htaccess line and how can I access it with php after rewrite ?

Comment: You may better rewrite as `www.domain.de/value` and redirect internally with parameter = value

Comment: no, I need the format like I explained :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
www.domain.de/paramter=value
```

is a pretty strange way of putting values. However, whenever a user enters such URL, you can make sure that the user lands on the correct page via below .htaccess on Apache server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^=]+)=(.+)$ /?$1=$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=53dc007b-3781-4d1d-80c6-5f0234cdf11a

This way, your PHP code is intact and nothing needs to be changed on the backend code. If you wish to make a permanent redirection, make `R = 301`.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
$g = $_GET;

$new_str = '';
foreach($g as $key => $value) {
    $new_str .= "$key=$value";
} 

echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ."/". $new_str;
```

Using the following URL:

`http://site.test/i.php?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3`,

It will return:

`site.test/p1=1p2=2p3=3`

Basically this code loops through the $_GET parameters and then grabs the key and the value, turns them into a string and then write a final URL with the string. You can format the output as you wish.